# How to access same keys inside dictionary of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d = {'A': {'1': [0.6, 0.5, 0.4],
           '2': [0.7, 0.8, 0.6],
           '3': [0.7, 0.8, 0.6]},

     'B': {'1': [0.7, 0.5, 0.5],
           '2': [0.7, 0.8, 0.7],
           '3': [0.7, 0.8, 0.7]},

     'C': {'1': [0.7, 0.4, 0.5],
           '2': [0.8, 0.6, 0.6],
           '3': [0.8, 0.7, 0.7]},

     'D': {'1': [0.6, 0.5, 0.5],
           '2': [0.7, 0.6, 0.6],
           '3': [0.7, 0.7, 0.6]}}
```

I want to get the value of '3' inside all the keys ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), all at once without using for loop.

Comment: You could use a dictionary comprehension. Or install glom https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: why no for loop? (and: `dict` should not be used as variable name).

Comment: `list(map(lambda d: d['3'], dict.values()))`, although this does not mean that there is no looping going on under the hood.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you want to do that:

```
print([d['3'] for d in dict_.values()]) # as said in the comments, do use dict as var name
```

this prints out

```
[[0.7, 0.8, 0.6], [0.7, 0.8, 0.7], [0.8, 0.7, 0.7], [0.7, 0.7, 0.6]]
```

Comment: ...that is a `for` loop.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify as well that the original post requested using no `for` loops, however this is practically impossible as SOME sort of looping structure will be necessary to ensure each dictionary is accessed (either a `while` or `for`)

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I know, but often the OP just doens't want an explicit for loop.

Comment: that is explicit... `list(map(lambda d: d['3'], dict.values()))` is not explicit... but i agree: there is no way (while keeping it general) to do that without looping...